# How do I store a selected result from a jQuery autocomplete list?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to build a small web app that allows a user to search for a game using the Giantbomb API, select the name on the list, and that game then goes into a top 10 list that can be sorted later on.

After much wrestling with jQuery UI Autocomplete, I have managed to get it to display the name of the game, but I would then like to store the full set of retrieved data for that game somewhere to be added to the list.

Here's what I have so far (most is from snippets I've found elsewhere):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
src = 'http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search/?api_key=myapikey&format=json';

$("#gameSearch").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: src,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                query : request.term,
                resources: "game",
                field_list: "name,original_release_date,image,platforms,publishers,developers"
            },
            success: function(data) {
              response($.map(data.results, function(item) {
                return { 
                    label: item.name,
                    value: item.name
                }
            }));
            }         
        });
    },
});
});
```

This gives me a list of games that match the search term when entered into the search box, but I'd like to somehow use jQuery UI Autocomplete's `select` function to push the full data from the `field_list` into some sort of array to be displayed, and I'm struggling to get it to work no matter where I put the `select` function.

Comment: What is *"full data from the field_list"* ..?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the game ID from the autocomplete selection in another input and when that input changes, make a call to get the game data for the selected game. I can't really test the below in a fiddle due to ajax limitations, but hopefully you get the gist.

HTML

```
<input id="gameSearch" />
<input id="gameId" />
<table id="results">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var fields = "name,original_release_date,image,platforms,publishers,developers";
    var fieldsArray = fields.split(',');
    var $table = $('#results');
    $table.find('thead').append('<tr></tr>');
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldsArray.length; i++) {
        $table.find('thead tr').append('<th>' + fieldsArray[i] + '</th>');
    }

    var results = data.results[0];

    $('#gameId').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: src,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                query: {
                    id: $('#gameId').val()
                },
                resources: "game",
                field_list: fields
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var results = data.results[0];
                var $tr = $('<tr></tr>');
                for (var j = 0; j < fieldsArray.length; j++) {
                    $tr.append('<td>' + results[fieldsArray[j]] + '</td>');
                }
                $('#results tbody').empty().append($tr);
            }
        });

    });

    $("#gameSearch").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: src,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    query: request.term,
                    resources: "game",
                    field_list: fields
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.results, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name,
                            value: item.id
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#gameId').val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
});
```